# XOR from only OR and AND

Tags: bitwise-operators, xor, bitwise-and

How do you do the XOR bitwise operation if you only have available the AND and the OR operations?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you need NOT as well.

Comment: @Oded nope, I just want to know. I'm programming in a scripting environment which only has AND and OR, but neither NOT or XOR, and I need XOR. You guys at StackOverflow sure are quick to judge something as homework.  Also, I don't understand that link, I had already looked at it before posting the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a NOT to create an XOR = (a && !b) || (!a && b) is the simplest way to put it

Comment: You need NOT otherwise it's not possible. If it doesn't have NOT (what scripting environment is this that *doesn't* have NOT -- that's a fairly fundamental omission) -- then you should just be able to use conditional logic to invert the bit... `if (x == 0) x = 1`, then it should be straightforward.

Comment: No NOT? Seriously? That's not funny. (Oh ana @nixon: NOR works as well; but it's no fun with NAND and NOR)

Comment: Is it permissible to use arithmetic operators, such as `+` and `-` ? If so then see my answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating my own scripting language - ChrisScript - you just need something like:

```
#!/bin/chrish

bit XOR (bit A, bit B)
{
   bit notA;
   bit notB;

   IF (A == 0) notA = 1 ELSE notA = 0;
   IF (B == 0) notB = 1 ELSE notB = 0;

   F = ((A && notB) || (notA && B));

   RETURN F;
}
```

Even without NOT, it can be emulated like this. But this is the best solution you're going to get without having some form of inverter. I find it hard to believe you don't have some form of inverter availble -- what scripting environment are you using?

Comment: A very limited Javascript environment.

Comment: Also, I need to do it int  by int, not bit by bit, since I can't get individual bits, for lack of bit shifting operators.

Comment: Define "very limited" -- do you have the actual javascript engine you're using (e.g., Microsoft JScript)? Is this part of some proprietary thing, if so, what product and version? It would be nice to have as much information about your environment as possible.

Answer (score 16):

Truth table for AND

```
  A  B  AND
  T  T  T
  T  F  F
  F  T  F
  F  F  F
```

Truth table for OR

```
  A  B  OR
  T  T  T
  T  F  T
  F  T  T
  F  F  F
```

Truth table for XOR

```
  A  B  XOR
  T  T  F
  T  F  T
  F  T  T
  F  F  F
```

So, XOR is just like OR, except it's false if A and B are true.

So, (A OR B) AND (NOT (A AND B)), which is (A OR B) AND (A NAND B)

```
  A  B  OR  AND NAND [(A OR B) AND (A NAND B)]
  T  T  T    T    F        F
  T  F  T    F    T        T
  F  T  T    F    T        T
  F  F  F    F    T        F
```

Not sure if it can be done without NOT or NAND

Comment: I think we all know what those operations do an how their truth tables look like. The question is, can you combine the first two to form the third, and if so, how?

Comment: I was starting my answer in the event that it was homework.  To be a direction rather than an answer.  I don't think it can be done.

Comment: Since the latter half which is (NOT (A AND B)) is the same as ((NOT A) OR (NOT B)), the entire can also be written as (A OR B) AND ((NOT A) OR (NOT B)), or (A+B)(!A+!B). The (A+B) handles the part where either A or B are true, the (!A+!B) handles when both A and B are false, the AND in between makes sure that both parts are true for the entire expression to be true.

Answer (score 11):

`(a XOR b) = ((a OR b) - (a AND b))`, or in other words, the union set minus the intersection set.

Code example (in javascript):

```
var a = 5;
var b = 12;
var xor = (a | b) - (a & b); // result: 9
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have arithmetic operators such as `+` and `-` in addition to bitwise AND (`&`) and OR (`|`) then you can do bitwise XOR like this:

```
int bitwise_XOR(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b) - (a & b) - (a & b);
}
```

The reason this works is that we are doing a full add, which is equivalent to XOR when the sum for any given bit position is <= 1, and then we're correcting for the case where a carry is generated (1 + 1) by subtracting `2 * (a & b)`.

Note that this works even when the intermediate terms overflow, assuming we have "normally behaved" integers (2's complement, modulo 2 wraparound for overflow, etc).

Comment: [gcc 6.x onward is smart enough to transform this to `a ^ b`](https://godbolt.org/z/WTl4Uk)

Comment: `(a | b) - (a & b)` may be more efficient.  It starts with non-exclusive OR, then clears the bits where both inputs were set.  (The value being subtracted from always has a set bit at those positions, so there's no borrow/carry propagation into other bits.)  Credit tor @harold for suggesting this in a comment on [How to XOR on a CPU that doesn't have an XOR instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32018545).  Oh, that's Zack's answer here.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, I like that solution - I think one of the other more recent answers uses this too.

Answer (score 5):

"The systems ({T, F}, and) and ({T, F}, or) are monoids."

"The system ({T, F}, xor) is an abelian group" which has the property of invertibility unlike monoids.

Therefore, 'and' and 'or' fail to construct 'xor' operation.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Relation_to_modern_algebra

Answer (score 4):

In C:  `x ^ y = (x & ~y) | (~x & y)`

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia's entry on XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) goes over this in detail. Probably a good first place to check before aksing a SO question.

If you already have bits you don't care about masked off, it seems to me the easiest way to do it (as far as writing the code goes anyway) is to just use your not equal operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
  PrintF('%-10s XOR',[inttobinbyte((10 OR 12)-(12 AND 10))])
```

> > > 00000110  XOR

Answer (score -1):

i am pretty sure that the formula below is correct:

a xor b = not((a and b) or not(a+b))

Comment: Read the question again. NOT is not available.

Comment: + is also not a boolean operator last I checked let alone an AND or OR operation

Answer (score -1):

in python

```py
...:def xor(a,b):
...:     c = (not a) and b
...:     d = (not b) and a
...:     e = not c
...:     f = not d
...:     g = e and f
...:     h = not g
...:     return h
```

Answer (score -4):

Best advice is to look up XOR in reference manuals and encyclopedia sites on the net and then write code or script which does the same as the description of what a XOR built-in function does and use your own return or status values. We can not tell you how to do that type of bit compares from within the software community.