# How to negate a number in IJVM?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, ijvm, mic-1

I was thinking of a way to implement a `NOT` operation/instruction for IJVM so that I could write a multiplication JAS method, but I'm having trouble trying to implement a negation method.

Can anyone help out with a way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are various ways to calculate the one's complement of a value, i.e. `NOT`:

```C
not_x = NAND(x, x) = NAND(x, ~0);
not_x = NOR(x, x) = NOR(x, 0);
not_x = -x - 1; // because in 2's complement -x = ~x + 1
not_x = 0xFFFFFFFF - x;   // assuming 32-bit computer
not_x = x XOR 0xFFFFFFFF; // or x XOR ~0
...
```

I don't know about IJVM but as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJVM) it supports only 4 arithmetic operations `IADD`, `ISUB`, `IAND` and `IOR`. You can use `ISUB` to achieve this

Now for more fun we can do `not_x = x XOR ~0 = (x OR ~0) - (x AND ~0)`
since [`a XOR b = (a OR b) - (a AND b)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5377173/995714). An alternative solution is to use a lookup table

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Heh, I'm so used to x86 / SSE that I was thinking `NAND(x, x);` would always be zero.  I was thinking of `ANDN` (which NOTs one input before AND), rather than `NAND` (which NOTs the output of an AND).

Comment: @PeterCordes yes. Among the architectures I know only MIPS has `nor` and a `not` will be done by `nor $dst, $src, $zero`. IMHO `nand` or `andn` would be more useful